# ASP.Net ReportViewer causes flickering in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, reportviewer

In the HTML generated by the ReportViewer there is the following line of code (I've tried ot make it more readable by removing the superfluous information)

```
setTimeout("frames['ReportViewer1TouchSession0'].location.replace('/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?...&TimerMethod=KeepAliveMethodReportViewer1TouchSession0...", 0);

function KeepAliveMethodReportViewer1TouchSession0() {   
setTimeout("frames['ReportViewer1TouchSession0'].location.replace('/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?...TimerMethod=KeepAliveMethodReportViewer1TouchSession0....", -1703027296);
}
```

When the Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd is called it makes a GET request that returns the following HTML:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript">parent.KeepAliveMethodReportViewer1TouchSession0();</script
```

> 

So in effect it becomes a recursive function and because KeepAliveMethodReportViewer1TouchSession0 calls a set timeout with a negative timeout value, in Firefox it's called immediately, in about 10 seconds Firebug logs over 150 GET requests in one minute there are over 700 requests logged. This causes Firefox's Stop button and cursor to flicker like crazy.

If anyone knows how to adjust the timeout on the keepalive request so it's something sane I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and when I made session timeout to something around 10000, it stopped flickering on firefox and chrome. I am not sure why, but it fixed that issue. I am a newbie in ASP.Net community , so I would like to know the relation between reducing the session timeout (previously I kept it at 120000) and reportviewer flickering on firefox when the application is on IIS (no issue with development server).

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is couple of years old, but I had a similar problem today and found a solution here:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=331a0a766d6da660&hl=en

It's a bit of a hack that creates a custom control inheriting from `ReportViewer` which replaces the offending JavaScript by overriding the `Render()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure... but it's worth noting that this control exposes a cross-site scripting vulnerability through the TimerMethod parameter. Not too much documentation on the issue, but be careful. :)